# What is a good beginner level book on neuroanatomy?

Tags: neuroscience

I'm looking for a beginner level book on neuroanatomy. I haven't any background in neuroanatomy, other than what I learnt back at school. I'd like to take up a post grad neuroscience course to help with my research and knowledge of neuroanatomy would help me understand neuroscience better.

Comment: I think this may be too broad, and a "shopping" question, so it will likely be closed.  It largely depends on what you meant by "what I learnt back at school".  Was it an undergraduate course?  A applied/practical course for medical workers/therapists, etc?  Check out [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Sidmans-Neuroanatomy-Programmed-Learning-Lippincott/dp/0781765684/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1351641795&sr=8-1&keywords=sidman%27s+neuroanatomy) I used it as a refresher before taking a grad level course.  It's very mechanical [con't]

Comment: and it reinforces the prior lessons as you go, there's a lot of writing and copying (I don't know how well that would work in the Kindle edition, so getting the spiral bound might be better), so check the preview before you buy it to see if it will fit your learning style.

Comment: If you're just looking for an atlas of the human brain, I find [Jurgen Mai's atlas](http://www.amazon.com/Atlas-Human-Brain-Third-Juergen/dp/012373603X) extremely helpful.

Comment: @FranciscoD unfortunately, this question is outside the scope of our site. Stack Exchange sites focus on *objective* questions 8witha  single correct answer*. Recommendations for books are off topic. **However**, our chat system is a good place to get book recommendations, would you like me to create a chat room for you to request recommendations for neuroanatomy books?

Comment: Also, after you find a book on neuroanatomy, please **do** return to ask some questions about it!

Comment: I crated [the following chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2452/cogsci-mod-room) for people to share book recommendations with you, FranciscoD. Please let me know if I can help further!